# Python 3.10/Django 3.2.7: No module named 'MySQLdb'

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, django

This week I started working home and tried installing my project on my PC but it won't work.

I cloned the git repo, installed MySQL Workbench and Server and stuff, installed Visual C++ stuffs
and loads of modules from my requirements.txt.

But when I try to run `./manage.py migrate` it spits out this:

```
$ py manage.py migrate
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\lisa-\projects\register\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line 15, in <module>
    import MySQLdb as Database
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'MySQLdb'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\lisa-\projects\register\manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\lisa-\projects\register\manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\lisa-\projects\register\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\lisa-\projects\register\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "C:\Users\lisa-\projects\register\venv\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\lisa-\projects\register\venv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 114, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "C:\Users\lisa-\projects\register\venv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 301, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "C:\Users\lisa-\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\lisa-\projects\register\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\models.py", line 3, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "C:\Users\lisa-\projects\register\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\base_user.py", line 48, in <module>
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  File "C:\Users\lisa-\projects\register\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 122, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))
  File "C:\Users\lisa-\projects\register\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 326, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "C:\Users\lisa-\projects\register\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\options.py", line 207, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
  File "C:\Users\lisa-\projects\register\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\connection.py", line 15, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self._connections[self._alias], item)
  File "C:\Users\lisa-\projects\register\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\connection.py", line 62, in __getitem__
    conn = self.create_connection(alias)
  File "C:\Users\lisa-\projects\register\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 204, in create_connection
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "C:\Users\lisa-\projects\register\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 111, in load_backend
    return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
  File "C:\Users\lisa-\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "C:\Users\lisa-\projects\register\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line 17, in <module>
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module.
Did you install mysqlclient?
```

Now I *did* install mysqlclient:

```
$ pip install mysqlclient
Collecting mysqlclient
  Using cached mysqlclient-2.1.0-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl (180 kB)
Installing collected packages: mysqlclient
Successfully installed mysqlclient-2.1.0
```

All of this is happening with a newly made venv using python 3.10, Django 3.2.7 and SQL Server 8.0
I googled about 2 hours which didn't help at all, because all I could find was "use pip install mysqlclient", which I obviously did. Sometimes I find things like "install using a wheel file". But I can't find a wheel file for 3.10. Or "use pip install mysql-python" or something like that but then I get an error saying I need Visual C++ 14.0, which I'm pretty sure I have...

So, I'm lost. Please please help me out.

Comment: Did u install python-mysqldb?

Comment: that doesnt exist...